# Asphostportal IIS6 vs IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net, sql, asp-classic

I have two shared accounts at asphostportal. One uses IIS 6 and one uses IIS7. On both I have websites in Classic ASP.

On the IIS 6 account, when I make an error in code and upload it then try to access that page, I get an error message that looks like this:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0400'
Expected statement
/file.asp, line 2
```

It tells me the error code and gives a line number. I usually look at that line and figure out the problem.

With IIS 7 I upload the file and navigate to the page and I get this:

```
Server Error
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

That's it. No useful information. I have no way of debugging this page without setting up IIS and MS SQL in the exact same configuration as it is on asphostportal on a local computer (this is my work computer so that's not going to happen).

I talked with someone at asphostportal. He says they are still tweaking IIS 7 configurations and can't give me an answer to why it is behaving like this.

Is there anything I can do, some kind of file I can set up (like an ASP.NET web.config file) to get the same kind of error messages on my IIS 7 account as I have on my IIS 6 account?

Answer (score 0):

In general from a security perspective it is actually desired that error messages go to a log and do NOT get exposed to the visitor of a site.

1. It is bad form on so many levels
2. errors might contain privileged information such as database connection strings, credentials and other details a malicious visitor might abuse.

Some background [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1453791/2952385) and on [MS support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301309)